# remove object from an array java

Tags: java, arrays

My practice problem says to"this method returns an array that has the elements of the specified

```
 // array of Objects, with the Object at the specified index removed.

    // the returned array should be smaller by one and have all elements

    // in the same relative location to each other. YOU MAY NOT USE

    // A LIST :)

Object[] remove(int index, Object[] arr){"
```

I have come up with this so far, and I'm not entirely sure it works. Can you guys please take a look and give me some feedback on how to fix it so I can do this "remove" properly.

```
public static remove(int index, Object[] arr){
int counter = 0;
int temp = 2;
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int[] second = new int[arr.length-1];

    for(int i=0; i< arr.length;i++){
        if(i != temp){
            second[counter] = arr[i];
            counter ++;

        }
        //return second;
    }
```

Comment: `remove` needs a return type.  Also, you never use the `index` parameter.  Other than that, you're really close.

Comment: how should i incorporate the index part of it?

Comment: public static remove(int index, Object[] arr){
int counter = 0;
int index = 2;
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int[] second = new int[arr.length-1];

    for(int i=0; i< arr.length;i++){
        if(i != index){
            second[counter] = arr[i];
            counter ++;

        }
        //return second;
    }

Comment: `index` is the index of the element you want to remove.  Looking at your code, you already know how to skip the index that you want to removed.  You just called it the wrong thing.

Comment: so if i change temp to index, would this work as intended?

Comment: OK, the code in the comments is closer--but you've sabotaged your `index` parameter by declaring a variable with the same name.  Take out the variable declaration.  You don't need it.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to include a new problem. Instead, create a new question.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static Object[] remove(int index, Object[] array) {
    Object[] newArray = new Object[array.length - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (index > i) {
            newArray[i] = array[i];
        } else if(index < i) {
            newArray[i - 1] = array[i];
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Comment: I made newArray according to the problem. Now you can return that array or do whatever you want with it.

Comment: I just updated my question with a second part, can you guys help me with that too? please

Comment: @chicagobears9023 you should consider selecting the best answer to your original question

Answer (score 0):

You would have to copy over all elements, besides for the one at `index`, into a new `array` and return that.